# Is it possible to add a reference to a web application in the free express version of VS for WP7?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7.1

Hi my question is this: I want to add a push notification to my WP7 application, and have read the [A Really Long Post About the Windows Phone 7 Push Notification System](http://www.thisisfanzoo.com/Blog/JeffF/archive/2010/08/02/a-really-long-post-about-the-windows-phone-7-push.aspx) explination. Now this is pretty to-the-point stuff, except for this little part, where the line

> `var svc = new NotificationService.NotificationServiceClient();`

is added. I think that this is just a reference to the web application of the developer. Is that correct, is this indeed a reference to the web application? And if so, how to implement that in the VS express for WP7, if indeed possible
I have already created a web application, but this is in the VS Web Development Express IDE, and working in the VS Express for WP7 IDE, want to add a reference to this web application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in the blog post the code you listed is intended to be called from an application other than the one on the phone.  There are other ways of sending a tile update from within the phone.

**Clarification after comments...**

In the majority of cases, sending notifications to the device is handled by server-side or desktop application code and not from the device itself.  If you have a service which is sending out notifications to the devices with the app installed, then you should ideally follow the patterns laid out by MS themselves.  In short, the steps are as follows.

1) The phone app registers itself with the MPNS (Microsft Push Notification Service) servers.
2) The phone app receives a unique URL to which notifications are sent.
3) The phone app sends this url to your service by whatever means are best for the app (usually a call to a WCF service) *
4) Your service calls the MPNS service to send the notification to the phone
5) The phone app receives the message and acts upon it as appropriate.

The bit you are probably thinking about is the highlighted step (3).  This is usually the only call out to an external source that you need to code manually in the notification scenario (registering with MPNS is handled by internal classes).

Given that this is the bit that you need to put most thought into, and that your question is about adding a reference to a web application there may be a bit of confusion here.  The two ways I have seen this data get passed around are

1) Call a WCF service (which may b hosted in a web application, and can be added with "Add Service Reference in VS), or
2) Posting data directly to a web page that deals with the posted data and stores it for later us.

In either case, you won't need to "add a reference" to a web app.  1) means adding a service reference in VS, which I believe you can do in the free dev environment, and 2) involves hand crafting an HttpWebRequest to post the data.

Comment: If you're thinking about the [tile update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769548(v=vs.92).aspx) class, I already looked into that, but it's more than just updating the background, also sent multiple users certain data. Basic stuff, but need to reach a wide range of users ( preferibly all =3  )

Comment: I had thought about the service reference, but only after an emberassins discovery, to which I will not further get into xD 
Thanks alot!

Comment: @GeekPeek - you can't leave it like that.  Confess and purge yourself of the stigma! :)

Comment: =P Only after a while did I realize: Bro you gotta publish that stuff xD   
So now I published it to localhost. ( first time webdeveloper user =P )    
BTW, how can I connect to a local host? I published to an IIS Express Site, but the URL is htpp://localhost:#####/

Comment: LOL - we've all been there in one way or another. :)  Do you mean how to add a reference to a local web service?  If so, just copy the URL into the Add Service Reference url box...

Comment: Well, I published, using the File System as Publish method, 
Then for target location, I browsed to Local IIS/ and then created a new IIS Express Site, wp7. 
So everything seems to go fine, it opens and publishes to the local host: Connecting to http://localhost:#####/ 
But this URL is not a valid one is it? I mean, I cannot simply copy-paste this into the service reference. I already tried =P
But when I add the would-be URL, says that there is no endpoint listener to accept the message. So, how to retrieve the URL?
VS WEb development does state that the project has been published

Comment: Can you try debugging the web app from within VS Web Dev (Press F5)?  Does that open your browser and point to the right place?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7238/discussion-between-geekpeek-and-zombiesheep)